# create a control programmatically using MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

I just wonder how to do it. 
I write :

```
CEdit m_wndEdit;
```

and in the button event handler (dialog app),
I write :

```
m_wndEdit.Create(//with params);
```

but I still don't see the control appear in the UI.

I actually wrote this in the button handler :

```
CWnd* pWnd = GetDlgItem(IDC_LIST1);
CRect rect;

pWnd->GetClientRect(&rect);

//pWnd->CalcWindowRect(rect,CWnd::adjustBorder);

wnd_Edit.Create(ES_MULTILINE | ES_NOHIDESEL | ES_READONLY,rect,this,105);

wnd_Edit.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);

this->Invalidate();
```

`id 105` doesn't exist. (I used it in the `Create` member function of `CEdit`). I just put it in there. isn't it supposed to be the id you want to give to the new control ? Should it already exist ?

Comment: Did you start off with creating a MFC project with a wizard on Visual Studio?

Comment: yes, i did create an MFC project with a wizard.

Comment: Can you give the exact parameters used for creation?

Comment: Hi aJ, I edited the question to include the exact parameters.

Comment: Check what is the return value of Create ? Also check  the resource id 105 really exists?

Comment: Did you try by adding flag WS_CHILD? Also, just wondering what exactly is "this" ? Is ListBox visible? Edit control creation has "this" as parent.

Comment: Naveen, id 105 doesn't exist. I just put it in there. isn't it supposed to be the id you want to give to the new control ? should it already exist ?

Comment: Naveen, I solved the problem using the code you posted down.
now, I want to control to occupy the same position as a previsou ListBox I created (exactly same position).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check with the following set of flags as the example mentioned in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ywby5fkc(VS.80).aspx):

```
   pEdit->Create(ES_MULTILINE | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP | WS_BORDER | ES_NOHIDESEL | ES_READONLY,
      rect, this, 105);
```

Answer (score 4):

- The Invalidate() is not necessary
- Add the WS_VISIBLE flag to your create flags, you don't need the ShowWindow
- You are creating the button on the location where IDC_LIST1 is - you probably want to do pWdn->Destroy() after the GetClientRect()
- The id you pass to Create() can be anything, of course if you want to handle messages from this button later you'll need to use the correct id. In that case it's easiest to manually add an entry to resource.h.
- What do you mean with 'I put this code in the button event handler' - which button? A different one from the one you're trying to create, I may hope? Does your code get called at all, does it stop when you put a breakpoint in? What's the value of wnd_Edit->m_hWnd after the call to Create()?
- wnd_Edit is a member of your dialog, right, and not a a function local variable?

Comment: One more thing, you're missing the WS_CHILD flag. Try with only WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, those are the only two flags you really need for any control.

Answer (score 0):

What is wnd_Edit exactly? If it's a local variable in that function, that is likely the problem. The CWnd destructor destroys the window associated with the CWnd. So when wnd_Edit goes out of scope, the edit box is destroyed too.
If that's not it, check the return value of Create(). Is it NULL? If it is, check the value of GetLastError().